# 3 row layout, 100% height: 1 auto, 1 auto with scroll, 1 fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to create a page layout that has: a **header** which will expand to match its content, a **footer** that has a fixed height (which will never change) and a **content** section that fills the distance between the two that will scroll when necessary.

The difference between this and many other [3 row questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=3%20row) asked on SO is that I need the header to be fluid not fixed.

Here's an example of what I am after. It works perfectly in Chrome, however 40% of the target demographic use IE7 and this doesn't work in any version of IE.

It's worth viewing it as a full page.

```css
html,
body,
form {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table .tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.table .tr.header {
  background: #ccc;
}

.table .tr.content {
  height: 90%;
}

.table .tr.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.table .td {
  display: table-cell;
}

.innerContent {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr header">
    <div class="td">
      <b>Header</b>
      <br />expands to show all available content
      <br />Other content
      <br />Some more content
      <br />Even more content
      <br />Additional content
      <br />Extended content
      <br />Enhanced content
      <br />Ya ya ya
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr content">
    <div class="td">

      <div class="innerContent">
        <b>Content</b>
        <br /> Will fill the remaining space and will scroll if necessary
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr footer">
    <div class="td">
      <b>Footer</b>
      <br/> Has fixed height and will never change.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Quirks

I can't use FlexBox because of IE7 although I would if there was a Polyfill available (I can't find one that supports IE7)

I can use HTML Tables (but would prefer not to).

I'm happy to use a JavaScript solution as long as its airtight, meaning if the content in the header changes the height, the content height needs to update as well; in fact, the version I am working with at the moment uses the following JavaScript to set the height of the content area:

```
function _makeContentScrollable() {

    var $template = $(".table"),
        $content = $template.children(".content");

    $content.height(($(window).height()) - ($content.offset().top + $footer.outerHeight(true, true)));

}
```

This is re-called onresize but I'm unsure of the best way of calling this when the header height changes an example would be from an expanding/collapsing element in the header, short of calling a callback function on every script that might affect the height of the header which seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: IE7 doesn't support `display: table/table-row/table-cell`. Why don't you use default `display: block`?

Comment: @cdm I'm quite happy to use display: block if you can show me how you would implement it?

Comment: @ChrisSpittles You don't need to use those. Check out my answer and let me know if it suits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything other than `position`ing. Check this out, which uses:

- `position: fixed`
- `padding`

This would give you a layout with fixed, scrolling (auto), fixed layout.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}

body {padding: 70px 0 50px;}

p {margin: 10px 0 0;}
p:first-child {margin: 0;}

.header, .footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footer {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px; bottom: 35px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus consequuntur tenetur amet quisquam, fuga nobis eligendi perspiciatis saepe inventore nam nihil, ducimus id soluta accusantium iusto! Modi itaque vel laudantium.</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam iure id culpa provident autem dolor, ea sit excepturi accusamus deleniti maxime repudiandae minima expedita eligendi, quam iste ullam cumque. Nesciunt!</span>
    <span>Itaque dolorem repudiandae qui repellendus error non inventore possimus cum! Praesentium nobis laboriosam illum voluptas quidem reiciendis incidunt, rem? Sapiente nemo, quam officia eveniet maiores sint. Culpa, modi eveniet vel.</span>
    <span>Asperiores non, facilis ratione placeat culpa, saepe dicta obcaecati, nesciunt blanditiis iste nostrum! Rem, suscipit. Nesciunt voluptas aliquam deleniti autem vitae repudiandae, hic, similique vel. Eius omnis ex voluptatum at?</span>
    <span>Enim facilis rem dolore tempore numquam iste sapiente id molestias cupiditate accusamus laborum eius consequatur magnam sequi iusto obcaecati officiis, nostrum? A eum error praesentium, in eos aperiam voluptatibus pariatur?</span>
    <span>Ipsam cumque, ab sunt explicabo dolores voluptates repellat aspernatur, molestiae, corporis, impedit blanditiis minus praesentium facilis deserunt alias sequi adipisci a. Numquam explicabo, odit fugiat reprehenderit fugit dolor aliquam nulla.</span>
    <span>Qui libero accusamus, eveniet quo ducimus temporibus quia consectetur nulla, dolores obcaecati fuga officiis excepturi sed error esse architecto necessitatibus assumenda aliquam at quidem quae illo! Blanditiis doloribus voluptatum, facilis.</span>
    <span>Ipsa inventore beatae quibusdam praesentium sunt omnis nesciunt eos incidunt accusantium adipisci, vitae dicta, perspiciatis repellendus, laudantium quam eius consequatur minus, illum reprehenderit. Tempora culpa officiis itaque veritatis vitae rem.</span>
    <span>Temporibus debitis repudiandae molestias praesentium expedita a aperiam quia veniam sequi delectus, harum atque incidunt consequatur tenetur exercitationem dolor at mollitia ea ad! Laborum, provident. Illum iste nam cumque dicta!</span>
    <span>Est commodi tempore quos nisi voluptatem aperiam totam laudantium vero autem quisquam explicabo labore sapiente, ea quas tenetur doloremque pariatur iure excepturi repellendus quia harum sint, perspiciatis! Saepe asperiores, labore.</span>
    <span>At quidem cum iusto pariatur dolor dolorem autem, corporis ipsum libero ipsa possimus fugiat aperiam dicta labore beatae ducimus veniam, molestiae nemo, cumque. Veniam mollitia itaque, aliquam porro hic enim!</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere perspiciatis magni iusto porro, nam quis, vel architecto rerum provident adipisci eveniet delectus deserunt, beatae dolore! Maxime quibusdam non, suscipit perspiciatis.</span>
    <span>Id dolorem assumenda, minus repudiandae velit facere atque quam sunt sapiente cum? Explicabo necessitatibus ipsam pariatur? Consequuntur exercitationem, sequi porro temporibus architecto a est, similique distinctio harum dicta libero accusantium.</span>
    <span>Ipsa corrupti repellat quaerat ratione sapiente unde dolor mollitia possimus at, voluptates architecto aliquid suscipit, natus porro, iusto perferendis. Optio error, aspernatur. Quaerat hic nobis soluta suscipit eveniet dignissimos, pariatur.</span>
    <span>Nemo aspernatur vitae non assumenda, similique sapiente totam porro laborum iste saepe facilis, reiciendis placeat impedit natus, itaque ipsam voluptatibus fugit ratione optio, sit iusto. Delectus ipsa officia voluptatem minima.</span>
    <span>Sequi vero vel cupiditate porro ipsam, voluptates ad deleniti sunt magni ex adipisci dicta error amet eveniet cum facilis perferendis nemo cumque. Eveniet similique quaerat voluptas ex velit, labore molestiae.</span>
    <span>Quibusdam iusto provident, neque amet, explicabo corrupti quia tempore voluptatibus dolorem dolorum sequi ex quidem tempora reprehenderit praesentium quod dignissimos. Laudantium, praesentium consequuntur. Dolore sequi, quos. Nobis blanditiis, porro aperiam?</span>
    <span>Natus eius ex ullam nam magnam, facere cupiditate facilis animi soluta maiores reprehenderit illum rem quae, sit velit mollitia excepturi at dolorum explicabo. Ducimus animi, aliquid voluptas cupiditate quos odio!</span>
    <span>Quo magni nostrum, asperiores delectus numquam qui cum impedit minus laborum explicabo, ab repellat aliquid nihil rem sunt praesentium, quaerat dolore quibusdam aut? Temporibus itaque perferendis cumque reprehenderit, quis recusandae?</span>
    <span>Aspernatur quod at neque quaerat quidem architecto earum facere nisi, fuga vero deserunt eaque necessitatibus officiis, tenetur iste? Expedita maxime dolorem blanditiis sed exercitationem praesentium facere, commodi amet quis nemo.</span>
    <span>Dolor atque laboriosam, provident tempora. Fugit delectus quidem modi cum voluptates, vel obcaecati iure reiciendis. Sit ad, sed tempora nobis atque consequuntur dolore ducimus voluptas. Sint animi mollitia cumque id.</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum dolorem libero blanditiis nobis consequuntur corporis excepturi laudantium ea explicabo facilis dolores fugit, est, voluptatum adipisci incidunt magni! Iure obcaecati, facere.</span>
    <span>Ducimus quidem voluptate voluptas est fuga consequatur pariatur, accusamus, deserunt quisquam excepturi. Culpa autem quia veritatis cupiditate soluta, quisquam, corporis assumenda, minus esse odit expedita consequatur aut laboriosam incidunt dolorem.</span>
    <span>Ipsa aliquam eos velit repudiandae, porro ipsum aliquid et tenetur autem minus quisquam officia deleniti ut reprehenderit commodi natus quis, ab dolor repellat nostrum nobis eaque quo. Nulla, veritatis aspernatur.</span>
    <span>Odit quisquam nam, facere obcaecati neque, eligendi dicta quos esse veniam quasi dolore vitae voluptatum autem corrupti iure vero ipsum unde, iusto ipsam at optio doloremque. Cumque necessitatibus, quisquam mollitia.</span>
    <span>Provident culpa inventore rerum nemo itaque reiciendis, architecto adipisci laudantium, error, quidem labore omnis cupiditate aspernatur blanditiis magnam doloribus eveniet quasi. Similique incidunt eius, placeat laudantium ipsa blanditiis error libero.</span>
    <span>Illum reiciendis exercitationem, cumque corrupti quibusdam fugit sit perferendis adipisci sunt eos ut placeat sequi excepturi esse porro veritatis recusandae non iste magnam unde ea ab aliquam natus, explicabo. Sapiente.</span>
    <span>Fuga velit autem, nemo facilis enim earum nam voluptas omnis adipisci laudantium dignissimos, sint ad quibusdam minima ipsa quaerat consequatur officiis repellat ut ab, eius, voluptate quos assumenda! Maiores, necessitatibus!</span>
    <span>Voluptatum amet deserunt saepe est maiores laborum, in quas deleniti hic iure animi debitis cum earum, qui possimus quisquam porro doloremque, sed eaque nemo aliquam labore dicta voluptatibus? Quibusdam, animi.</span>
    <span>Nam dolorem non illo alias minus quis ratione eveniet nesciunt, tempora aperiam placeat fuga iure quidem quia sed iste voluptate consequatur, ducimus assumenda maiores impedit, saepe. Fuga perspiciatis unde eum?</span>
    <span>Nesciunt sapiente, fugit deserunt, repellendus velit, possimus nobis doloremque rerum magni beatae dicta eos, quaerat nam labore. Cupiditate commodi necessitatibus ipsam laudantium dolores, nihil nam totam similique, neque provident accusantium.</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt asperiores recusandae corrupti quod magnam ea ratione eveniet excepturi, temporibus dolorem labore, impedit illo, debitis. Assumenda harum, consequatur obcaecati reiciendis. Aspernatur!</span>
    <span>Sequi inventore blanditiis, non exercitationem saepe explicabo sapiente mollitia nam tempore enim, optio! Aliquam quam, magnam voluptates et laborum excepturi autem nostrum explicabo dolores harum vero cum fuga nesciunt, cumque.</span>
    <span>Fugit, eligendi optio veniam, quo enim ipsum minus neque natus, vero eaque, consequatur corporis nesciunt quis quod mollitia sapiente recusandae suscipit doloribus possimus. Alias reprehenderit quod perferendis architecto ipsa, consequatur.</span>
    <span>Nihil architecto minima, inventore, officiis itaque alias odio quibusdam amet? Minus quae aliquam, maxime. Nam pariatur aut quis, distinctio est, itaque. Blanditiis laboriosam molestiae deleniti commodi vel praesentium aperiam consequatur?</span>
    <span>Qui a dolorum dicta, nihil perspiciatis reprehenderit rem esse voluptas porro, quod beatae error excepturi quam tempora, illo. Similique minus, unde fuga! Earum nesciunt maiores cumque quisquam quam iste numquam!</span>
    <span>Nisi accusamus, nesciunt vel explicabo veniam laudantium sit delectus debitis id numquam mollitia accusantium itaque sed. Voluptatum, nostrum laborum illo labore veritatis, minima nesciunt repellat, a neque maiores est magnam!</span>
    <span>Aspernatur ab reprehenderit doloribus ut hic deleniti eaque veritatis. Consequuntur non mollitia blanditiis vitae illo in cum rem minus a dicta optio dolorum facilis vero, at vel beatae earum. Corporis?</span>
    <span>Ad quos expedita officiis odio autem! Neque non doloremque voluptatum, laudantium cupiditate voluptas voluptate earum explicabo dolores, nam nobis distinctio ad, aliquid recusandae deleniti doloribus architecto illo molestiae laboriosam odio?</span>
    <span>Soluta, minima expedita, dolorem explicabo enim alias amet nam, sunt neque dolor saepe rerum dignissimos hic itaque accusamus atque provident. Ut at eum deserunt aspernatur ullam expedita tempora, exercitationem nemo.</span>
    <span>Voluptatem, quae, praesentium? Maxime veritatis earum, autem quia minus quae asperiores dolor quo veniam non tenetur vero officiis beatae magnam ipsum aliquam odit rerum illum architecto provident voluptate. Architecto, aperiam.</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet molestiae quibusdam officiis, sapiente maiores id cupiditate libero autem saepe magnam, quo necessitatibus dolorum iure fugiat perspiciatis praesentium tempora dolore ad.</span>
    <span>Omnis et perspiciatis blanditiis nulla, non ipsam impedit dolore molestias eos nesciunt nam pariatur delectus temporibus tenetur esse, corrupti voluptatum commodi debitis! Maxime, doloribus hic reprehenderit in iusto provident optio.</span>
    <span>Cupiditate amet, consequuntur neque esse architecto dolorum distinctio. Tenetur sapiente tempore possimus libero nam suscipit in commodi vitae, id eligendi cupiditate expedita facilis accusamus praesentium, a vero ipsum repellat explicabo?</span>
    <span>Vero fuga dignissimos officiis. Voluptatum error iste, nihil pariatur odio voluptatem molestiae, sit ipsum officiis ex, sed modi ut doloremque provident expedita accusantium earum quidem eveniet ratione ea aperiam. Molestias!</span>
    <span>Sed earum consequuntur ut ea quod officiis animi, nemo expedita sint ullam magni impedit dicta minima debitis, quidem, repudiandae architecto dolorem delectus? Aspernatur porro tenetur, quae quasi iusto earum, id.</span>
    <span>Voluptas dolore voluptates enim cum quasi dicta atque vitae aliquid omnis incidunt possimus quis molestiae, necessitatibus porro molestias, recusandae autem consectetur, officiis dignissimos in. Quas incidunt odio obcaecati quod aspernatur.</span>
    <span>Dolorum, temporibus adipisci dignissimos quod, modi ipsam voluptates ipsa autem necessitatibus perferendis magni, veritatis repudiandae maxime veniam repellendus quo minima quibusdam porro illo neque delectus molestiae facere ab. Reiciendis, sapiente.</span>
    <span>Facere quam qui expedita tenetur optio reprehenderit odit aliquid, officia corrupti vel commodi deserunt nesciunt recusandae beatae quas assumenda iusto ex, quibusdam. Doloremque similique, sit nulla nemo tempora voluptates eum?</span>
    <span>Magnam voluptas eveniet qui voluptatum cupiditate, natus blanditiis ipsam consequuntur, ex quia, odit. Velit maxime sint repellat totam, sit, nobis in temporibus quia pariatur praesentium magni ipsa harum eveniet, laudantium.</span>
    <span>Dolorum amet laudantium maiores, modi fugit, harum sint ratione ex ad nihil at velit quam numquam corrupti, esse dolor praesentium laboriosam explicabo. In, itaque, suscipit adipisci nihil ab facilis praesentium.</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, autem ea nemo et provident, architecto minus deleniti laborum expedita earum omnis, voluptas officiis deserunt. Laudantium nesciunt fugit quae nulla reiciendis.</span>
    <span>Officiis, vero magni aspernatur earum soluta qui animi optio nihil pariatur ad, molestiae possimus a omnis cum impedit ab atque ducimus, quas? Iste est alias voluptatem amet itaque assumenda obcaecati?</span>
    <span>Reiciendis veniam laboriosam neque, vero odio nisi placeat vitae provident quia debitis omnis praesentium numquam dolores adipisci explicabo nihil recusandae, repudiandae velit esse expedita blanditiis! Rerum mollitia cum suscipit veniam!</span>
    <span>Quaerat voluptatibus laborum, laudantium nisi dolorum officia id soluta cumque. Ex, voluptate doloremque placeat quo harum dignissimos architecto ipsam adipisci cum nisi repellendus quisquam ipsa dolorem odio aspernatur. Cum, distinctio.</span>
    <span>Voluptates ut, quam earum non repellat sit aperiam facere id iste totam sint quidem nemo odit delectus ab culpa, sed voluptate ipsam quos commodi magnam. Ipsum quos reiciendis molestiae nesciunt.</span>
    <span>Dolorum quis rerum architecto consectetur! Magni suscipit adipisci voluptates reiciendis eos et minus, inventore quod quisquam aliquid, molestiae, fuga nostrum ipsa! Velit debitis distinctio consectetur sed esse iste aspernatur, sit.</span>
    <span>Dignissimos at, doloremque enim vero voluptatem mollitia fugit soluta corporis veniam similique sed temporibus deserunt quisquam eligendi, ducimus ut molestias sunt quibusdam. Perferendis officia, vero facere iste, libero voluptate numquam!</span>
    <span>Repellat laboriosam eum magnam, nam explicabo assumenda fugit fugiat, cumque, laudantium a itaque repudiandae. Omnis, laudantium, expedita? Nisi iusto at aut, recusandae, non veniam harum tempora voluptates laboriosam sint laudantium.</span>
    <span>Quasi quae rerum labore accusamus, optio est pariatur excepturi. Voluptatem tenetur fugit doloribus molestiae officiis fuga commodi voluptate, distinctio magni accusamus, labore sequi eligendi reprehenderit, id dicta ullam magnam ipsum.</span>
    <span>Quidem dolor in reprehenderit, consectetur. Tempore consectetur provident aperiam ab ducimus obcaecati maiores illum voluptas ipsam beatae. Beatae porro magni, sint assumenda fugiat illum, consequuntur atque unde eligendi, quod id!</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non ipsum illo, facere soluta, enim placeat repudiandae exercitationem sed numquam ratione maxime eligendi dignissimos, ex voluptatum eaque aperiam! Veritatis, pariatur, deleniti.</span>
    <span>Pariatur nulla ducimus, labore saepe temporibus, doloremque, minima totam odit harum corporis omnis impedit quod iusto mollitia culpa aliquid aut laborum earum et magnam fugit vitae deserunt vel. Atque, dignissimos.</span>
    <span>Fugiat accusamus aspernatur corrupti, porro? Reiciendis placeat cupiditate ea dolorem magnam eligendi molestias distinctio numquam consequuntur fuga ad, atque quaerat saepe beatae delectus explicabo laudantium suscipit porro sed corrupti accusantium.</span>
    <span>Omnis dolor pariatur iure nulla quasi exercitationem eum obcaecati perferendis laudantium, alias voluptatem sunt, sapiente ducimus similique totam, architecto minus, culpa. Impedit, veritatis, vero. Error nesciunt nemo laudantium doloremque harum.</span>
    <span>Tempora ipsum obcaecati, nemo, a exercitationem, modi commodi explicabo voluptates possimus in, suscipit corporis beatae ad alias veniam culpa ipsa? Optio, quas, enim! Omnis, non, reprehenderit est illum numquam doloribus!</span>
    <span>Impedit reiciendis quia perferendis, odit natus unde qui explicabo laudantium ipsam dolorem eligendi veritatis. Neque, sapiente mollitia consectetur tenetur delectus repellendus nihil quae magnam suscipit amet voluptatibus itaque, magni possimus!</span>
    <span>Perferendis impedit voluptas aliquid reiciendis, ipsam rem consectetur suscipit corrupti tenetur. Ducimus saepe, quibusdam debitis hic veniam aliquid laborum cumque rerum minima magnam itaque, quod, excepturi blanditiis illo officia aliquam?</span>
    <span>Cupiditate quasi aut adipisci at sed eaque quo, nulla aperiam labore rem ducimus illum ut quaerat nemo earum fugit accusantium, doloribus soluta molestiae sequi, odit quis quam sapiente voluptates nostrum!</span>
    <span>Impedit pariatur ab quod hic rem illo voluptatibus, ipsum ipsam ut magnam quasi amet quae ipsa quo maiores est suscipit non sint delectus inventore. Autem, quibusdam, odit! Odio, dolorum, quo.</span>
    <span>Qui ipsum ipsa sit laudantium commodi eligendi itaque, beatae tempora tempore. Porro expedita nisi minus eaque magni, culpa quibusdam. Doloremque dolorum cupiditate hic! Voluptatem esse hic error sit ab nihil.</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit!</div>
```

**Updated** according to comments.

**Update:** For dynamic height, you could consider using this JavaScript (jQuery) code:

```
$(function () {
  var resizeWin = function () {
    $(".content").css("top", $(".header").outerHeight());
  };
  resizeWin();
  $(window).resize(resizeWin);
});
```

**JSBin: http://output.jsbin.com/wikeketequ**

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. There are a couple of issues that I can see, the first being that the header cuts off the content underneath which is a deal breaker and also I find the scroll bar confusing because it extends from top to bottom. Thanks though.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles The header doesn't cut off anything beneath, that's the main point of having the `body`'s top padding.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles The scroll bar thing is true. We aren't using frames or inline split things here. But yeah, it would be better. I will make a new snippet, where you can see the scrollbar for the scrolling content alone. If that's okay?

Comment: @ChrisSpittles And finally, don't worry, the header doesn't hide anything.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles Check the updated snippet. Full screen or half screen. Every where it works.

Comment: The top padding on the body is a fixed value of 70px. If the content inside the header grows beyond 70px the content becomes hidden. The header has to grow without obscuring the content underneath as my example shows in chrome. Thanks for your continued efforts though it is appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles That's the only problem buddy. Can we use JS to fix that issue?

Comment: Thanks for the updated snippet. If you view the snippet at 1920 x 1080 the padding is too much and there is a gap under the header and above the footer because the padding values are fixed and not fluid.

Comment: I am in the same resolution. Lemme check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110136/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-chris-spittles).